# Font doesn't display correctly in .Net MAUI

Tags: fonts, maui

I'm experiencing problems using a font in MAUI. The project in which the font is used is very very simple (the general Hello World!).
The font is placed in the correct directory (Resources/Font), is placed in the MauiProgram.cs but the font doesn't display. Does anybody know why?

```
namespace MauiTest;

public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                fonts.AddFont("Creamer.ttf", "MyFont");
            });

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

[image: Font in the right position]

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 version 17.4.3.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that there is a compatibility issue with the font you are trying to use. Can you try using a different font to see if it works? If that doesn't solve the issue, you could try adding the font to the system and then referencing it in your code.

Another possibility could be that the font file is not being included in the build output. You can check this by right-clicking the font file in Visual Studio and selecting "Properties." Ensure that the "Build Action" property is set to "Content" and the "Copy to Output Directory" property is set to "Copy if newer."

Comment: @Beham Unfortunately your second suggestion failed with error : **@(Content) build action is not supported** Trying the first one.....

Comment: Great! You were right about the first suggestion! Trying with a font in my PC it works!!!!!! Than you very very very much!!!!!!

Comment: Now that you know the font is okay: If you plan on shipping this app to others, who may not have this font installed, you’ll need to solve the original problem. Uninstall from your pc, keep experimenting.